# Basic Java : fractions rounded to 0

Tags: java

When I have a fraction for example `(5 / 6)` then Java will just round this to 0.

For example:

```
System.out.println(1-(1/2));
```

This prints out 1 instead of 1/2 ie 0.5.

How can I tell Java that these should be floats or doubles instead of rounded to integers?

Comment: Most children learn integer division in primary school but many seem to forget it. In Java, C, C++ etc you need to use a floating point value (or cast) to say it is not an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly use a double literal :

```
System.out.println(1-(1.0/2));
```

Or you cast one of the number to a double.